# Reg exp to find number

Tags: regex

Hi I have a some text where I want to find all occurrences like the following and replace with that same number minus the apostrophes.
'1' or '164' 
(pattern = apostrophe number apostrophe)

Reg Ex makes my brain sore.
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "number"? Can it be negative? Can it be non-integer? Can it be expression in scientific notation? Can it be in hexadecimal?

Comment: The numbers are 1 thru 164 - sorry I wasn't clearer

Comment: What flavor of regular expressions? PCRE? POSIX? Java? Something else?

Comment: I was just going to do it in notepad++ - no idea what type. sorry ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'(16[0-4]|1[0-5][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]?)'
```

matches a number between 1 and 164, enclosed in apostrophes. To remove the apostrophes, replace the matched text with backreference `\1`.

Comment: This '([0-9]+)' worked for me - I didn't need to be that exact - thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this can help you (example using Javascript):

```
var x = "some_text:'68' and other:'109', finally:'05'";
var res = x.replace(/'([0-9]+)'/g,"$1");
alert(res); //some_text:68 and other:109, finally:05
```

Comment: This will match any number, not just between 1 and 164.

Comment: thanks - appreciated. I'm doing it in notepad++. This '([0-9]+)' certainly finds them but I can't seem to be able to replace with the number

Comment: @Chin: are you using Javascript?

Comment: no just using notepad - thanks I've solved it - appreciate the help though